# В случайном элементе взять подэлемент

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Есть большой список элементов

```
<div class="scxIndicators_groupedItemHeader">
```

Хочу случайным образом выбрать один из них, а потом у него  достать его подэелементы (первый кликнуть а у второго достать имя)

```
 <div class="scxIndicators_button_simple scxIndicators_button_add">
 <div class="scxIndicators_groupedItemName">
```

Есть такая функция случайного выбора этого элемента и скрола к нему:

```
 links = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('.scxIndicators_groupedItemHeader')
 link = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)]
 wd.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", link)
```

А вот как выбрать его подэлементы не знаю, может кто сможет подсказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Достаем все элементы по классу
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.scxIndicators_groupedItemHeader');
// Берём случайный из списка
const randomLink = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)];

// Берём первый дочерний элемент и кликаем
const firstChild = randomLink.querySelector('.scxIndicators_button_simple .scxIndicators_button_add');
firstChild.click();

// Достаём второй дочерний элемент и берём из него текст
const secondChild = randomLink.querySelector('.scxIndicators_groupedItemName');
const contentText = secondChild.textContent;
console.log(contentText);
```

Comment: пробовал такой вариант, но вот не срабатывал, и думал что ж я не правильно делаю... а оказываеться, что нужно сначала глаза было открыть нормально, я пытался нажать на '.scxIndicators_button_add',  а не на '.scxIndicators_button_simple.scxIndicators_button_add', и не понимал, чего ж мне вечно ругается, что элемент не может найти))) спасибо большое!